# ¿Qué propiedades cumplen la misma función que objet-fit aplicada a un video pero para IE?

Tags: html5, css3

===========================================================================

## YA QUEDÓ, GRACIAS

En el banner del sitio web que estoy haciendo coloqué un vídeo, esta llenando un div con la mismas proporciones de width y height.

```
     .slider { <!-- Esté es el estilo del slider en general -->
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            height: 95.5vH;
            z-index: 900;
            font-family: Raleway;
        }
        video {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 95vH !important;
            box-sizing: border-box !imprtant;
            margin: auto;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: center;
        }




<div id="slide1">
         <div class="video-responsive">
           <video  id="vid" class="video" loop="loop"  muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay">
              <source src="Videos/VideoPVManpower_rev0.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              Tu navegador no soporta video HTML5.
           </video>
           <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script src="JavaScript/canvas-video-player.js"></script>
        <script>
            var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);

            if (isIOS) {

             var canvasVideo = new CanvasVideoPlayer({
             videoSelector: '.video',
             canvasSelector: '.canvas',
             timelineSelector: false,
             autoplay: true,
             makeLoop: true,
             pauseOnClick: false
             });

            }else {

            // Use HTML5 video
            document.querySelectorAll('.canvas')[0].style.display = 'none';

            }   
     </script>
     </div>
```

Funciona a la perfección sobre Chrome, pero no funciona del todo bien en Internet Explorer ¿Que puedo hacer para que cumpla la misma función sobre IE?
[image: Así luce en IE tanto en el Edge como en el otro.]

[image: Y así es como luce en Google Chrome, quiero que tenga este mismo aspecto en todos los navegadores]

Cualquier otra recomendación diferente a mi duda es bienvenida.

Comment: Las imágenes ayudan, pero realmente lo útil es el código: añade tu HTML y CSS para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Lee cómo crear un [mcve] en el centro de ayuda y edita tu pregunta para añadir esa información.

Comment: Listo, ya incluí el HTML de mi slide y el CSS, tratare de preguntar cada vez mejor, gracias @AlvaroMontoro .

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box !imprtant;` tiene que ser `box-sizing: border-box !important;`  Te falta una "o", la propiedad de css que mencionas no la soporta internet explorer en varias versiones. Prueba solo dejando en la etiqueta video la propiedad `width = 100%` me parece.

Comment: @Cig solo dejando el `width = 100%` si llena el ancho de la pantalla, pero no solo el 95% del alto del viewport,que es lo que que quiero hacer.

Comment: @AngelRivas podrías poner la respuesta a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Listo, lo único que hice fue poner un

```
overflow: hidden;
```

en el las propiedades del slider general y los "dots" los puse con un

```
top: 95vW;
```

Y con eso quedó la solución, no esta llena de buenas practicas pero respondió bien en todas las resoluciones de dispositivos.